Prisma unknown argument id (works with every other model)
I am currently working on a project where I am migrating a legacy app into a NextJS application with PrismaJS.
In order to do this I have a bunch of mjs files that can be run to take the data from the original data (using standard MySQL query) and importing the data into the new database using Prisma. Due to this I need to retain all of the original database ids.
This has been working fine for all of the tables I've done so far (nearly 30 tables) but I have a table that keeps throwing a weird error that makes no sense.
Below is the prisma schema for the tables affected.
odel ConfigGroup {
  id            Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String        @db.VarChar(255)
  config_items  ConfigItem[]
  config_values ConfigValue[]

  @@map("config_groups")
}

model ConfigItem {
  id                 Int                   @id @default(autoincrement())
  config_group_id    Int
  name               String                @db.VarChar(255)
  title              String                @db.VarChar(255)
  type               ConfigItemType
  function_call_name String                @db.VarChar(255)
  description        String                @db.MediumText
  value              String                @db.MediumText
  placeholder_text   String                @db.VarChar(255)
  storage_type       ConfigItemStorageType @default(TEXT)
  required           Boolean               @default(false)
  config_group       ConfigGroup           @relation(fields: [config_group_id], references: [id])
  config_values      ConfigValue[]

  @@map("config_items")
}

model ConfigValue {
  id              Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  config_group_id Int?
  config_item_id  Int?
  value           String       @db.VarChar(255)
  config_groups   ConfigGroup? @relation(fields: [config_group_id], references: [id])
  config_items    ConfigItem?  @relation(fields: [config_item_id], references: [id])

  @@map("config_values")
}

The config_group table is migrated fine using the below code
return nodePrisma.$transaction(async (nodePrisma) => {
            let [rows] = await this.getData("config_groups");

            for (const row of rows) {
                await nodePrisma.configGroup.create({
                    data: {
                        id: row.id,
                        name: row.Name
                    }
                })
            }
            console.log("Config groups successfully migrated");
        });

I then do the config_item table with the below:
return nodePrisma.$transaction(async (nodePrisma) => {
            for (const row of rows) {

                //Check that the config group id exist
                const configGroup = await nodePrisma.configGroup.findUnique({
                    where: {
                        id: parseInt(row.ConfigGroupID)
                    }
                });

                if (configGroup === null) {
                    continue;
                }

                let type;
                switch (row.Type) {
                    case "Text":
                        type = ConfigItemType.TEXT;
                        break;
                    case "MultiText":
                        type = ConfigItemType.MULTI_TEXT;
                        break;
                    case "Number":
                        type = ConfigItemType.NUMBER;
                        break;
                    case "Email":
                        type = ConfigItemType.EMAIL;
                        break;
                    case "Password":
                        type = ConfigItemType.DROPDOWN;
                        break;
                    case "Function":
                        type = ConfigItemType.FUNCTION;
                        break;
                    case "Dropdown":
                        type = ConfigItemType.DROPDOWN;
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.error("Unknown config item type: " + row.Type);
                        return;
                }

                let storageType;
                switch (row.StorageType) {
                    case "TEXT":
                        storageType = ConfigItemStorageType.TEXT;
                        break;
                    case "JSON":
                        storageType = ConfigItemStorageType.JSON;
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.error("Unknown config item storage type: " + row.StorageType);
                        return;
                }

                //No idea why the id can't be set in this case, keeps throwing an error stating id is an unknown argument
                await nodePrisma.configItem.create({
                    data: {
                        id: row.id,
                        //config_group_id: configGroup.id,
                        config_group: { connect: { id: configGroup.id } },
                        name: row.Name,
                        title: row.Title,
                        type: type,
                        function_call_name: row.FunctionCallName,
                        description: row.Description,
                        value: row.Value,
                        placeholder_text: row.PlaceholderText ?? "",
                        storage_type: storageType,
                        required: row.Required === "1"
                    }
                })
            }

As you can see, both in config_group and config_item I set the id column based on the row data from the previous database, this works on config_group but on config_item I get the below error:
PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma.configItem.create()` invocation:

{
  data: {
    id: 1,
    ~~
    config_group: {
      connect: {
        id: 1
      }
    },
    name: "DefaultQuoteAssignees",
    title: "Default Quote Assignee",
    type: "FUNCTION",
    function_call_name: "GetAllActiveUsers",
    description: "What user should be automatically selected",
    value: "[\"9\",\"10\"]",
    placeholder_text: "",
    storage_type: "JSON",
    required: false,
?   config_values?: ConfigValueCreateNestedManyWithoutConfig_itemsInput
  }
}

Unknown argument `id`. Available options are marked with ?.

I've no idea why its saying the id is an unknown argument. The id is 1 which is correct. If I remove this id field from the insert, then it works and imports everything with the id being auto incrmented, so why in this case is the id not valid for me to be able to set it as I've done elsewhere?

The reason you can't pass id for the ConfigItem model might be the relations it has and the way Prisma handles it.
To solve this:

Temporarily remove @default(autoincrement()) from the id field of the ConfigItem model.
Run the Migration with prisma migrate dev.
Run your create script
finally Restore the Original Schema and re-migrate the Database.


Or you can also try using the upsert method.
Here is an example:
await nodePrisma.configItem.upsert({
  where: { id: row.id },
  create: {
    id: row.id,
    config_group: { connect: { id: configGroup.id } },
    // rest of your code
}});


The upsert threw the same error, but removing the auto increment default value did work, but it shouldn't make any difference. I've done the exact same thing on multiple tables without any problem. It doesn't make a lot of sense why it says its an unknown argument, but without the autoincrement it works, it still technically the same argument i am writing

Do other tables which you are talking about have a required relation field ?

Yea pretty much every table has one or more required and/or optional relations
